# iChat: Very slow transfer speeds/Port Restricted

Tags: file-transfer, ichat, router, network

I have a 12mbps connection, so I know that my ichat transfers should be super fast.  When I receive files from some people, my transfer rate is about 1k/sec, which is horrible.  Why would this be happening?  Do I need to do something with my router?

In the Connection Doctor it says Router Type: Port Restricted.

Comment: You'll probably need to modify your router's NAT settings.  What brand/model of router do you have?

Comment: I have a ZyXEL Q1000Z.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use these two documents to forward the appropriate ports on your router:

- [Using iChat with a firewall or NAT router](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1507) (apple.com)
- [ZyXEL Q1000Z: How to create a custom Application Rule](http://www.qwest.com/internethelp/modems/q1000z/pdf/Q1000Z_APPLICATION_FORWARDING_CREATE_RULE.pdf) (qwest.com)

If you have specific questions about port forwarding on your router, you could try asking over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/).